# Using Windows named pipes with ffmpeg pipes

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ffmpeg, pipe

I'm trying to use Windows Pipes to write data to input pipes in FFmpeg. I'm using the following command for FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -pix_fmt rgba -s 1280x720 -f rawvideo -y -i \\.\pipe\videopipe -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 -i \\.\pipe\audiopipe -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -b:a 320k -ar 44100 -vf vflip -vcodec mpeg1video -qscale 4 -bufsize 500KB -maxrate 5000KB OUTPUT_FILE
```

I tried connecting to it using the `CreateFile()` method but that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried with `CreateNamedPipe()` after starting to run the ffmpeg command but then it seems to wait for something else to connect.

I don't know in which order I have to call those two. Do I first need to create a Windows pipe and use the same name in FFmpeg or do I need to first invoke FFmpeg with the named pipes and then connect to it using `CreateFile()`?

Answer (score 1):

I've developed code to do it, maybe it will help. In my case i'm streaming an image and playing it in ffplay. I launch 3 threads one that creates pipe (in demo pipes the one who executes 'initializePipe') one that listens to pipe creation and launch ffplay and the writer thread who writes to the pipe the image.

demoPipes.cpp

```
#include "demoPipes.h"
using namespace std;

#define MAX_THREADS 100
//#define BUF_SIZE 255

void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction);

// Sample custom data structure for threads to use.
// This is passed by void pointer so it can be any data type
// that can be passed using a single void pointer (LPVOID).
/*typedef struct MyData {
    int val1;
    int val2;
} MYDATA, *PMYDATA;
*/

typedef struct
{
    HANDLE pipe;
    LPCSTR MEDIA_PIPE;
} Session;


int _tmain()
{
    Session* s = (Session*)malloc(sizeof(Session));

    s->pipe = NULL;
    s->MEDIA_PIPE = "\\\\.\\pipe\\screenRec";

    DWORD   dwThreadIdArray[MAX_THREADS];
    HANDLE  hThreadArray[MAX_THREADS]; 

    // Create MAX_THREADS worker threads.
    for( int i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        //create pipe initializer thread
        if(i==0){
            hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread( 
                NULL,                   // default security attributes
                0,                      // use default stack size  
                initializePipe,       // thread function name
                (LPVOID) s,          // argument to thread function 
                0,                      // use default creation flags 
                &dwThreadIdArray[i]);   // returns the thread identifier 
        }

        //create writer thread
        if(i>1){
            PipeMetaData* pipe_data1 = fetch_file("D:\\images.png", s->pipe);
            //PipeMetaData* pipe_data = createPipeMetaData(pipe_data1->file_vector,pipe_data1->byte_size);
            //pipe_data1->pipe =s->pipe; 
            hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread( 
                NULL,                   // default security attributes
                0,                      // use default stack size  
                send_media_to_recorder,       // thread function name
                pipe_data1,          // argument to thread function 
                0,                      // use default creation flags 
                &dwThreadIdArray[i]);   // returns the thread identifier 
        }
        //create recorder thread
        if(i==1){
            hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread( 
                NULL,                   // default security attributes
                0,                      // use default stack size  
                recorder_pipe_function,       // thread function name
                0,          // argument to thread function 
                0,                      // use default creation flags 
                &dwThreadIdArray[i]);   // returns the thread identifier 
        }

        // Check the return value for success.
        // If CreateThread fails, terminate execution. 
        // This will automatically clean up threads and memory. 

        if (dwThreadIdArray[i] == NULL) 
        {
           ErrorHandler(TEXT("CreateThread"));
           ExitProcess(3);
        }
    } // End of main thread creation loop.


    //for close RTP
    // Wait until all threads have terminated.
    WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    // Close all thread handles and free memory allocations.
    CloseHandle(s->pipe);
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}


void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code.

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message.

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR) lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR) lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR) lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    // Free error-handling buffer allocations.

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

clientpipe.cpp

```
#include "client_pipe.h"
using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI recorder_pipe_function( LPVOID lpParam){
    const char* MEDIA_PIPE =  "\\\\.\\pipe\\screenRec";
    //LPCWSTR MEDIA_PIPE_wchar = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\screenRec";

    //waits for server to initialize the media pipe.
    //wait_for_media_pipe(MEDIA_PIPE,10);
    WaitNamedPipeA(MEDIA_PIPE,1000);
    start_recording_session(MEDIA_PIPE);

    return 0;
}

void start_recording_session(const char* media_pipe){
    //initialize recording command
    char* command = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100+1);
    command[0] ='\0';
    strcpy_s(command,sizeof(char)*100+1,"start ffplay -i ");
    //strcpy_s(command,sizeof(char)*100+1,"ffmpeg -i ");
    strcat_s(command,sizeof(char)*100+1, media_pipe);
    //strcat_s(command,sizeof(char)*100+1, " -f matroska D:\\djhfifj.mkv");  
    std::cout << "Executing ffmpeg command\n";
    int i=system (command);
    std::cout << "The value returned was: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

ServerPipe.cpp

```
#include "server_pipe.h"

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    HANDLE pipe;
    LPCSTR MEDIA_PIPE;
} Session;

DWORD WINAPI initializePipe( LPVOID lpParam ) {

    printf("Creating an instance of a named pipe...");

    Session* s = (Session*) lpParam;
    LPCSTR MEDIA_PIPE = s->MEDIA_PIPE;

    // Create a pipe to send data
    s->pipe = CreateNamedPipeA(
        MEDIA_PIPE, // name of the pipe
        PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, // 1-way pipe -- send only
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, // send data as a byte stream
        1, // only allow 1 instance of this pipe
        0, // no outbound buffer
        0, // no inbound buffer
        0, // use default wait time
        NULL // use default security attributes
    );

    if (s->pipe == NULL ||s->pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        wcout << "Failed to create outbound pipe instance.";
        // look up error code here using GetLastError()
        return NULL;
    }

    wcout << "Waiting for a client to connect to the pipe..." << endl;

    // This call blocks until a client process connects to the pipe
    BOOL result = ConnectNamedPipe(s->pipe, NULL);
    if (!result) {
        wcout << "Failed to make connection on named pipe." << endl;
        // look up error code here using GetLastError()
        CloseHandle(s->pipe); // close the pipe
        system("pause");
        return NULL;
    }
}

PipeMetaData* fetch_file(char* file_path,HANDLE pipe){
    PipeMetaData* data = (PipeMetaData*) malloc(sizeof(PipeMetaData));

    //opening file
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(file_path,std::ios::binary);
    infile.seekg(0,std::ios::end);

    //get file byte size
    data->byte_size = infile.tellg();

    //fetch data to send
    data->file_vector =(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*data->byte_size);
    infile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
    infile.read(&(data->file_vector)[0],data->byte_size);
    data->packet = &(data->file_vector)[0];
    data->pipe = pipe;
    wcout<<data->byte_size<<endl;

    return data;
}

DWORD WINAPI send_media_to_recorder(LPVOID lpParam){
    PipeMetaData* p = (PipeMetaData*) lpParam;
    // This call blocks until a client process reads all the data
    DWORD numBytesWritten = 0;
    BOOL result = WriteFile(
        p->pipe, // handle to our outbound pipe
        p->packet,//&(p->file_vector)[0], // data to send
        p->byte_size, // length of data to send (bytes)
        &numBytesWritten, // will store actual amount of data sent
        NULL // not using overlapped IO
    );

    if (result) {
        wcout << "Number of bytes sent: " << numBytesWritten << endl;
    } else {
        wcout << "Failed to send data." << endl;
        // look up error code here using GetLastError()
        GetLastError();
    }

    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```